# Javascript multiples mouse clicks recording coordinates with markers

Tags: javascript, coordinates, markers

Below is the code that I have added to be able to click on an image 3 seperate places. The script will record the 3 coordinates and then pressing the caclulate button will add the 3 "X" axis's together. I would like to add a marker at each of the 3 locations when clicked. How can this be done? I have played with some code and can add a marker at one spot, but not all 3.

thanks for the help.

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>image test</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

var Point = 1;
var total;
var X1, Y1, X2, Y2, X3, Y3;

function FindPosition(oElement)
{
  if( typeof( oElement.offsetParent ) != "undefined" )
  {
    for( var posX = 0, posY = 0; oElement; oElement = oElement.offsetParent )
    {
      posX += oElement.offsetLeft;
      posY += oElement.offsetTop;
    }
    return [ posX, posY ];
  }
  else
  {
    return [ oElement.x, oElement.y ];
  }
}
 
function GetCoordinates(e)
{
 var PosX = 0;
 var PosY = 0;
 var ImgPos;
 ImgPos = FindPosition(myImg);
 if (!e) var e = window.event;
 if (e.pageX || e.pageY)
 {
  PosX = e.pageX;
  PosY = e.pageY;
 }
 else if (e.clientX || e.clientY)
   {
    PosX = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
    PosY = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
 }
 PosX = PosX - ImgPos[0];
 PosY = PosY - ImgPos[1];
 if (Point == 1)
 {
   X1 = PosX;
   Y1 = PosY;
   Point = 2;
   document.getElementById("x1").innerHTML = PosX;
   document.getElementById("y1").innerHTML = PosY;
 }
 else if (Point == 2)
 {
   X2 = PosX;
   Y2 = PosY;
   Point = 3;
   document.getElementById("x2").innerHTML = PosX;
   document.getElementById("y2").innerHTML = PosY;
 }
 else
 {
   X3 = PosX;
   Y3 = PosY;
   Point = 4;
   document.getElementById("x3").innerHTML = PosX;
   document.getElementById("y3").innerHTML = PosY;
 }
 
}

function Calc()
{
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = X1+X2+X3;
}

//-->
</script>

</head>

<body>

<img src="pic.jpg" width="473" height="715" alt="" id="myImgId" />
<p>Click on the image for the coordinates.</p>

<p><strong>First Point:</strong></p>
<p>X: <span id="x1"></span></p>
<p>Y: <span id="y1"></span></p>
<p><strong>Second Point:</strong></p>
<p>X: <span id="x2"></span></p>
<p>Y: <span id="y2"></span></p>
<p><strong>Third Point:</strong></p>
<p>X: <span id="x3"></span></p>
<p>Y: <span id="y3"></span></p>
<p><strong>total:</strong></p>
<p id="demo"></p>

<form name="form1">
<input type="button" name="calcbutton" value="Calculate" onclick="Calc();" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var myImg = document.getElementById("myImgId");
myImg.onmousedown = GetCoordinates; 
//-->
</script>

</body>
</html>
```